# OpenXML: Anyway to see if a Word Document fits one page

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk, wordprocessingml

While I doubt it, if I open up a word document using OpenXML sdk in C# and add some info, is there any way for me to see if it still fits one page?

If it doesn't I wan't to reduce font size on specific items I added until it fits.

I could write this algorithm if I had the current size in relation to page size with margins and all that.

Comment: I'm not aware of anything for the OpenXML SDK which does this for you already, but as you say, it could be done.  Not too bad for simple text only; worse if there are images and tables; and complex in the general case though.

Comment: No images but this is mostly based on variable number of items in a table.

Answer (score 1):

I ran across this example on another site, don't know if it'll work in your case, as it requires the Office PIA...

```
var app = new Word.Application();
var doc = app.Documents.Open("path/to/file");
doc.Repaginate()

var pageNumber = doc.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages").Value as int;
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Not sure what PIA stands for but it seems you actually have to run a word app and that's a no no. I'm thinking I have to look at the `Validate` object in the OPenXml namespace and see if it can do anything similiar.

Comment: Oh, sorry. PIA is a Primary Interop Assembly.  They are provided by Microsoft to help automate Office applications.  I think this site will help you navigate the Open XML file and find the page node: http://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/programatically-get-count-pagesslidessheet-in-microsoft-wordpowerpointexcel-2007/

Comment: Problem is that the docProps/app.xml is probably generated by Microsoft word and is not included if I create the docx in C#.